# How to group node elements in a <p> tag

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop, button

I was wondering if someone can help me out.  The issue I'm having is the '#' and 'spaces' are being displayed individually on their own line, what I'm trying to have is a layout like this (without the quotes at the end of each line):

"# # # #"

"# # # #"

"# # # #"

The code would display four '#' each line. The length is determined by the number the user is prompt with.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks again.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Q3 Display</title>

    <style>

        .resultText {
            display: inline-block;
        }


    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div>

    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">

        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#q3" aria-controls="q3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Q3</a></li>

    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">


        <!-- Question 3 Start -->
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane tab-pane active" id="q3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <pre>
                    Question 3 code:

                    </pre>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <!-- button -->
                    <button id="q3-button" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Question Three Solution</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">

                    <!-- result -->
                    <div id="result"></div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>


        <script>

            //Question 3

            //When the button is clicked, begin the function called start

            $("#q3-button").on("click", function () {
                start();
            });


            function start() {

            //Sets up user prompt
                var start = parseInt(prompt("How long would you like the side to be?"));

                //Determine if what was entered in prompt is a number
                if (isNaN(start)) {
                    alert("That's not a number, please retry.");
                    var start = prompt("Please re-enter a number.");
                }

                //Grabs the result div and assigns it a variable, will be used later on for result printing
                var element = document.getElementById("result");

                for (var i = 1; i <= start; i++) {


                    for (var j = 1; j <= 8; j++) {

                        if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) {


                            //Creates <p></p> element
                            var p1 = document.createElement("p");

                            //sets a class to the <p></p> element
                            p1.setAttribute("class", "resultText");

                            //Sets a variable to hold the text the <p></p> should contain
                            var node1 = document.createTextNode("#");

                            //Actually adds the text to the <p></p> element
                            p1.appendChild(node1);

                            //adds the <p></p> tag to the results div
                            element.appendChild(p1);
                        }
                        else {

                            //Creates <p></p> element
                            var p2 = document.createElement("p");

                            //p2.setAttribute("class", "resultText");

                            //Sets a variable to hold the text the <p></p> should contain (in this case an empty tag)
                            var node2 = document.createTextNode(" ");

                            //Actually adds the text to the <p></p> element
                            p2.appendChild(node2);

                            //adds the <p></p> tag to the results div
                            element.appendChild(p2);

                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        </script>

    </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Node.appendChild()` will put the new element to the end of the list of children of the node, or move the existing element to there.

In your code, if you want to print 4 `#` in a line, change this line:

```
p1.appendChild(node1);
```

to

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
    p1.appendChild(node1);
}
```

The reason that your code is printing out `#`s in separated lines is, element `p1` with a pair of tags `<p></p>` will add space before and after the content.

Try this HTML snippet and you will get it:

```
<p>Text1</p>
<p>Text2</p>
```

**EDIT**

if you want to include the quotes in your output, do it like this:

`var node1 = document.createTextNode('"#" "#" "#" "#"');`

That is, use single quote around the double quotes and put space in the element. You don't need to repeatedly insert multiple text nodes in order to output a line of something.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  The code seems to be outputting two groups of four '#''#''#''#' then the correct amount on the next line.

Comment: @fasteddie Can you tell me what exactly you want? Do you want to print N lines of `#` ?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is: The user enters a number, that number is the number of rows that will be displayed.  Each row would consist of four '#' and four spaces to look like this: 

"#"  "#"  "#"  "#" 


Thanks for your help.

Comment: @fasteddie if you want to include the quotes in your output, do it like this: `var node1 = document.createTextNode('"#" "#" "#" "#"');`, that is, use single quote around the double quotes and put space in the element. You don't need to repeatedly insert multiple text nodes in order to output a line of something.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I have it working now.